# The API applets can make such a bubble popup

Tags: applet, gtk, linux-mint, cinnamon

The API applets can make such a bubble popup.
How to make your own, so that its contents could fill any complex layout elements GTK UI XML or HTML and CSS?

It's about something more complicated than a simple vertical menu.

[image: http://x3.cdn03.imgwykop.pl/c3201142/comment_Oh6NXPi5Xo0HuI1D1HNyEVXkvYI32MOa.jpg]

In the documentation I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The class you want is GtkPopover. It is only available starting with GTK+ 3.12.